# Close Memory Stream with async Task Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, task-parallel-library

I have a Web Api function which uploads base64 image to Azure, I use async task method to do that. The problem is that the code execution gets stuck with the await word and never move next to close the stream ,even after uploading the photo and I don't get any errors either.

```
    public async Task<bool> UploadImage(string filename, MemoryStream uploadStream)
    {
            var blobClient = ConnectToAzure();
            CloudBlobContainer imagContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(Container);
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = imagContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);
            blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "image/jpg";                                                
            await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(uploadStream);
            uploadStream.Close();

            return true;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure it gets stuck instead of *uploading* ? `await` means the program will await *asynchronously*, ie without blocking other threads and definitely not the main thread. After it completes execution resumes on the original execution context.

Comment: BTW your code sends a JPG image, not Base64. Based64 is text.

Comment: my first guess would be you accidentally ignore exception. Add try/catch around 'await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(uploadStream);' and put breakpoint into catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `UploadImage(...)` in MVC/WebAPI Action Method, this action should to be async too

Answer (score -1):

Your uploadStream object's life cycle might end right after calling your await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(uploadStream) method to cause your UploadImage() method exits/ends earlier than expected. Could you please try moving your code to the parent scope of your UploadImage() method?

Comment: No, `await` **ensures** that execution will proceed only *after* `UploadFromStreamAsync` completes.

Comment: Yes, but the uploadStream is type of MemoryStream instead of FileStream. That's why I suspect that's root cause. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: What does the *stream* have to do with *await* ?

Comment: To be honest I am not sure about this UploadFromStreamAsync() method. I had a similar issue a couple days ago but my scenario was having a using (memoryStream) { ... await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(memoryStream); memoryStream.Close(); }. My line "memoryStream.Close()" never executed without any exception and I had to "unwrap"(not use) the using block to have that async method and memoryStream in the same scope to make it work. It's weird to me...

Comment: If you aren't sure about your own code don't post *answers*. BTW this is *not* an answer. At best it should be a comment. In any case, there's nothing uncertain about how `await` behaves. And explicitly calling `Close()`, ie `Dispose()` inside a `using` block isn't required.

Comment: You may have *blocked* the UI thread for example by using a `.Wait()` or `.Result` call, thus preventing `await` from returning

Comment: Oh I am so sorry. I am not quite familiar with this comment/answer platform. I will notice next time and many thanks for your advice.